# Move-ctor and copy-ctor not called

Tags: c++

Let's take the following C++ sample:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  std::string s;

  X() : s("X") { }

  X(const X& other) : s{other.s} { std::cout << "cpy-ctor\n"; }

  X(X&& o): s{o.s} { o.s = ""; std::cout << "move-ctor\n"; }

  X& operator=(const X& other) {
    std::cout << "cpy-assigned\n";
    s = other.s;
    return *this;
  }

  X& operator=(X&& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
      s = other.s;
      other.s = "";
    }
    std::cout << "move assigned\n";
    return *this;
  }
};

X f(X x) {
  std::cout << "f: ";
  return x;
}

X g() {
  std::cout << "g: ";
  X x;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  X x;
  X y;
  x = f(X());
  y = g();
}
```

If I compile it with gcc 4.8.2, I have the following result:

```
f: move-ctor
move assigned
g: move assigned
```

I do not understand why copy-constructor is not called when I am calling the g function.

I am just trying to understand when the copy or the move constructors are called.

Comment: Copy elision, return value optimization.

Comment: You are witnessing [named return value optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: You could just write `struct X { std::string s{ "X" }; };`. The compiler generated constructors and operators would works fine. As it is now, you have several mistakes in your implementations. For example, your move assignment doesn't do anything and your move constructor copies.

Comment: I am just trying to understand when the copy and the move constructor are called... that's why I wrote them in my structure but of course, I know that I can use the default one.

Comment: Why are you guys answering in the comments section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are correct to identify that there is, logically, a copy/move of the local variable `x` from inside `g()` when it is returned, a useful feature of C++ is that it can *elide* (i.e. skip) this operation in many cases, *even when the copy/move would have side-effects*. This is one of those cases. When performed, this is known as the [named return value optimisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

It's arguably less useful than it was before we had move semantics, but it's still nice to have. Indeed, [C++17 made it mandatory in some (select) cases](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/guaranteed-copy-elision/).

Comment: But if I want to be able to call my own copy-constructor, how can I do if there is this return value optimization !?

Comment: @klaus: Why do you need to force a copy? That seems weird.

Comment: I do not need to force a copy but because I thought copy-ctor was called with the return of my function I thought I could trace the call by "std::cout-ing" with my own copy-ctor...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, If I understand correctly your answer, you are suggesting that compiler can elide the copy/move **assignments** (which is the case of OP's code example, for `x` and `y`). But copy elision is only to elide copy/move **constructors** (not assignments). Please let me know if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: @AdvSphere: No, I'm talking about the returning of a value from the function, not the subsequent assignment of that value to `x`/`y` (which, AFAIK, can't be elided)

Comment: @AdvSphere: No probs, I'm glad!

Answer (score 1):

In C++ all the expressions are:

- lvalue
- prvalue
- xvalue

## Constructing an object

### - lvalue

```
Y x{};
Y y{x}; // copy constructor, x is an lvalue
```

### - prvalue - RVO

With RVO, which is enabled by gcc by default. This elides using the copy constructor and instead the object is constructed once.

```
X g()
{
  X x {}; 
  x.value = 10;
  return x;
}

X y {g()}; // X constructor get's called only once to create "y". Also 
           // y is passed a a reference to g() where y.value = 10. 
           // No copy/move constructor for optimization "as if" rule
```

### - prvalue - No RVO

Without RVO, in this case it depends. If the move constructors are explicitly or implicitly deleted, then it will call the copy constructor

**Copy constructor**

```
struct X { X(const X&) {}}; // implicitly deletes move constructor 
                            // and move assignment, see rule of 5

X g()
{
  return X{}; // returns a prvalue
}

X y {g()}; // prvalue gets converted to xvalue, 
           // "temporary materialization", where the xvalue has an 
           // identity where members can be copied from. The xvalue
           // binds to lvalue reference, the one from copy constructor
           // argument
```

**Move constructor**

```
X { X(X&&) {}}; // explicitly declared move constructor

X g()
{
  return X{}; // returns a prvalue
}

X y {g()}; // prvalue gets converted to xvalue, 
           // "temporary materialization", where the xvalue has an
           // identity where members can be moved from. The xvalue 
           // binds to rvalue reference, the one from move constructor 
           // argument
```

### - xvalue

```
X x {};
X y {std::move(x)}; // std::move returns an xvalue, where if move 
                    // constructor is declared will call it, other wise 
                    // copy constructor, similar to explained above for 
                    // prvalue.
```

## Copy/move assignment

### - lvalue

```
X x{};
X y{};

x = y; // call copy assignment operator since y is an lvalue.
```

### - prvalue

If the move assignments are explicitly or implicitly deleted, then it will call the copy assignment operator.

**Copy assignment**

```
struct X{ X& operator=(const X&); } // implicilty deletes move 
                                    // constructor and move assignment,
                                    // see rule of 5

X g()
{
  return X{}; // returns a prvalue
}

x = g(); // prvalue gets converted to xvalue, 
       // "temporary materialization", where the xvalue has an identity 
       // where members can be copied from. The xvalue binds to lvalue 
       // reference, the one from copy assignment operator argument
```

**Move assignment**

```
struct X{ X& operator=(X&&); } // explicitly declared move assignment        operator

X g()
{
  return X{}; // returns a prvalue
}

x = g(); // prvalue gets converted to xvalue, 
       // "temporary materialization", where the xvalue has an identity 
       // where members can be moved from. The xvalue binds to rvalue 
       // reference, the one from move assignment operator argument
```

### - xvalue

```
X x {};
X y {};

x = std::move(x); // std::move returns an xvalue, where if move
                  // assignment is declared will call it, other 
                  // wise copy assignment, similar to explained 
                  // above for prvalue.
```

Comment: Thank you for your really complete answer (:

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor is called when you instantiate an object using another object of the same type.

For example:

```
X x;
X y(x);
```

The last line in your code assigns a value returned from a function to an already constructed object. This is done via move assignment.

Comment: The return, however, could potentially require a move/copy. That's where the question is coming from.

Comment: Absolutely. I thought the return would require a copy for f and a move for g.